# Resize /system partition of Zenfone 5

Tags: partitions, asus-zenfone-5

I want to change my `/system` partition on my Zenfone 5. Its size is only 1259 MB.

Today I installed Resurrection Remix ROM so there is only 195MB free space on `/system` partition. System can't properly operate. I can't even flash GApps because it says that there is not enough space on system.

P.S. I don't think that RR ROM should take 1063MB of `/system` storage. I think I messed up partitions and stuff. Is there any way to return my partitions to the default state?